# I want to copy rows from one text file to another if it contains a certain pattern

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have one .txt document containing rs-numbers (first column) and other variants: 
head:

```
rs2925757 A 0.113329
rs10929982 T 0.113329
rs2119812 C 0.182322
rs7629805 A 0.182322
rs6771792 C 0.19062
rs11709077 G 0.157004
rs13083375 G 0.14842
rs13064760 C 0.14842
rs7638903 G 0.14842
rs4684847 C 0.14842
```

I have other txt documents looking like this (with rs-numbers in column 2):

```
--- rs181860478 30004551 C A 0.000 0.000 1.000 0 -1 -1 -1
--- rs187641010:30004588:C:A 30004588 C A 0.000 0.001 1.000 0 -1 -1 -1
--- rs678486:30004607:A:G 30004607 A G 0.204 0.961 0.983 0 -1 -1 -1
--- rs145540866:30004629:C:A 30004629 C A 0.000 0.000 1.000 0 -1 -1 -1
--- 12:30004702:C:T 30004702 C T 0.000 0.001 1.000 0 -1 -1 -1
--- 12:30004732:A:G 30004732 A G 0.000 0.099 0.999 0 -1 -1 -1
--- exm-rs147708347 30004743 A C 0.001 0.965 1.000 0 -1 -1 -1
```

Meaning that sometimes the rs-numbers stand alone in the column, sometimes they are followed by `:----------` and sometimes they start with `exm-`.

I want to be able to extract all the rs-numbers listed in txt file 1 from txt file 2. Any suggestions to how I can do that?

Comment: In these sorts of questions, you generally need to list what you expect the output to be for the shown inputs.

Comment: I just want an txt file output like txt document 2, only with just the rows of the rs-numbers listed in txt file 1.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the command as following.

```
grep -Fwe "$(awk '{print $1}' file1)" file2 >output.txt
```

This is getting first column of file1 and feed to `grep` as set of PATTERNs search in file2.

There is no matched data in your given sample data, but this works.

Comment: It's one problem doing it like this and that is that I get a lot of SNPs that I dont want. For instance rs153585 is in my list, but with this command I get all the rs numbers starting with rs153585, not just the one im after 

GWA-data-updated-chr10.005.impute_info:--- rs1535857:13203772:A:G 13203772 A G 0.704 0.935 0.969 0 -1 -1 -1


GWA-data-updated-chr10.005.impute_info:--- rs1535856:13217940:A:G 13217940 A G 0.900 0.923 0.982 0 -1 -1 -1


GWA-data-updated-chr10.005.impute_info:--- rs1535852:13243345:C:T 13243345 C T 0.057 0.937 0.990 0 -1 -1 -1

Comment: I got your point, please see my updated answer, thanks

Answer (score 0):

use the [join](https://linux.die.net/man/1/join) operator .
Assuming the separators are a space.

```
join -t ' ' -1 1 -2 1 \
           <(sort -t ' ' -k1,1 file1.txt) \
           <(tr ":" " " < file2.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | sort -t ' ' -k1,1 )
```

PS: for bioinformatics questions, you should use http://biostars.org